# Как добавить условие в dataProvider в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

С помощью `CRUD` с генерировал `GridView` на индексной странице.

На данный момент в `GridView` отображаются все элементы из таблицы в БД.

Хотел что бы не отображались все данные, а только те у которых например поле `some_id` в таблице равно `12`.

Пробовал так:

В место `$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);`

Написал

```
$query = SomeModel::find()->where(['some_id' => 12]);   

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
  'query' => $query,
     'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
      ],
]);
```

Вроде все получилось, но теперь не работает `searchModel`.

Или можно как нибудь добавить условие в строку

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

UPDATE:

На самом деле в контроллере `actionIndex` принимает параметр `some_id`, и после этого выводит данные у которых выполняется условие.

```
public function actionIndex($some_id){
    $searchModel = new SomeModelSearch();
    // Я сам закомментировал
    //$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    // И добал это
    $query = SomeModel::find()->where(['some_id' => $some_id]);                             
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: выложите полный код. Вот как нужно: $dataProvider->query->andWhere(['some_id'=>'12']);

Comment: `searchModel` у вас не работает по другой причине, только что проверил, такой вариант нормально работает, так что написал @UrmuzTagizade, надо больше кода

Comment: сейчас выложу код

Comment: @MasterAlex или вопрос у меня плохо сформулирован, или я плохо разбираюсь. Поэтому проще говоря я хотел получить только те данные удовл. условия динамически. Может по другому это делается

Comment: @MasterAlex Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, по моему вопросу:) [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694847/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-yii)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `$searchModel` в методе `search` в конце перед `return $dataProvider` добавьте свой запрос, к примеру вот такой:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['some_id' => 12]);
```

Comment: В принципе подошло. Только Я вместо 12 добавил `$_GET['some_id']` и все работает. 
Просто мне кажется что есть более красивое решение, чем мой `быдло_код`

Comment: @Xfirab более красивое решение, в контроллере делаете массив $inputParams в которые напихиваете аргументы, потом объединяете его с queryParams через array_merge и суете все это в модель search настраиваете нужные правила валидации для всех аргументов экшна и queryParams переданных в SerachModel и там уже внутри метода search цепляете andFilterWhere к $query. И не используйте сырые данные из $_GET

Comment: @Yaroslav Molchan Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, по моему вопросу:) [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694847/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-yii)