# Вывод данных из базы данных в yii

Tags: php, yii2, yii, php7

Здравствуйте.

Имеется файл index.php:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'value' => 'viewLink',
            'format' => 'raw'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'shortText',
            'value' => 'shortText',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

На странице с помощью этого кода выводятся записи из базы данных. Также на этой странице с помощью панели yii показывает в разделе Request следующее:

```
Route   'admin/education/index'
Action  'app\\modules\\admin\\controllers\\EducationController::actionIndex()'
```

Соответственно описываю `actionIndex(`):

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new EducationSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Затем описываю `EducationSearch()`:

```
class EducationSearch extends Education
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['id_sort'], 'integer'],
            [['video_obychenie'], 'integer'],
            [['title', 'text', 'video_path'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }
    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Education::find();

        $query->orderBy(['id_sort' => SORT_ASC]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['video_obychenie' => '2']);
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'text', $this->text])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'video_path', $this->video_path]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

То есть сейчас выводится данные, где `$query->andFilterWhere(['video_obychenie' => '2']);`, т.е. video_obychenie=2. И отображается все эти записи с помощью первого кода, который указал выше `<?= GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => $dataProvider,....`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как можно на той же странице вывести отдельным блоком записи у которых уже будет video_obychenie=3, т.е. `$query->andFilterWhere(['video_obychenie' => '3']);`

Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь:)

Comment: Записи выводить из этой же таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

В классе EducationSearch удалите строку

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['video_obychenie' => '2']);
```

У вас внизу есть

```
// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'id' => $this->id,
]);
```

Добавьте туда ваш фильтр:

```
// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'id' => $this->id,
    'video_obychenie' => $this->video_obychenie,
]);
```

Теперь вы можете задать любое значение свойству video_obychenie, например 3. В вашем случае это будет через GET параметр EducationSearch[video_obychenie]=3

Comment: а как вывести видео с `video_obychenie=2` и отдельно `video_obychenie=3`. На странице нужно отдельными группами выводить.

Comment: То есть мне надо и записи с `video_obychenie=2` и с `video_obychenie=3`. в отдельных местах на одной странице. Пробовал писать так: `$dataProvider = $searchModel->search2(Yii::$app->request->queryParams)`, т.е. обращаться ко второй функции `search2`, но что-то не получается.

Comment: И выводить надо с помощью также `<?= GridView::widget([.......` В моем коде еще возможно подключен код для поиска по записям. Поиск я не использую по записям.

Comment: Разобрался сам:) Спасибо Вам за то, что предложили свой вариант по отборке, но в вопрос был другой.